# SQLite coalesce problem when running django testcases

Tags: sql, django, testing, sqlite, postgresql

I am using django for running my project. And I am using postgresql_psycopg2 engine for my production db, but the test runner uses sqllite3 for running the tests. Keeping my production db(postgresql)in mind I tried building a query which uses "coalesce". But sqllite3 doesn't recognize this. How do I get pass this. I can use postgresql_psycopg2 even for my test running(just to avoid wastage of time), but its too slow. How do I get pass this?

Comment: This has been repeated ad nauseam but still - use the same DBMS for development and production.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sqlite does support [`coalesce`](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html) but requires at least two arguments.  I believe that the Postgresl implementation only requires one parameter while Sqlite requires at least two.  Perhaps you are using `coalesce` with only one parameter in Postgresql and that is breaking when moving to Sqlite?

Could you post the code that is failing?

Comment: You are absolutely right. I was not passing two arguments mandatorily. Thanks Andrew